# How to get index of tr in Bootstrap Vue table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

When I use a v-for in vue I make like this:

```
v-for="(test, index) in tests"
```

How can I make the same using Bootstrap vue? I want to get the index of all the TR.

```
<b-table
  :items="items"
  :fields="columns"
>
```

Comment: Where and how do you want to use this `index`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you may want diffirent thing but You might want to look at the solution.

If primary-key is not provided,  will auto-generate keys based on the displayed row's index number (i.e. position in the displayed table rows).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table small :fields="fields" :items="items" responsive="sm">
      <!-- A virtual column -->
      <template #cell(index)="data">
        {{ data.index + 1 }}
      </template>

      <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template #cell(name)="data">
        <b class="text-info">{{ data.value.last.toUpperCase() }}</b>, <b>{{ data.value.first }}</b>
      </template>

      <!-- A virtual composite column -->
      <template #cell(nameage)="data">
        {{ data.item.name.first }} is {{ data.item.age }} years old
      </template>

      <!-- Optional default data cell scoped slot -->
      <template #cell()="data">
        <i>{{ data.value }}</i>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fields: [
          // A virtual column that doesn't exist in items
          'index',
          // A column that needs custom formatting
          { key: 'name', label: 'Full Name' },
          // A regular column
          'age',
          // A regular column
          'sex',
          // A virtual column made up from two fields
          { key: 'nameage', label: 'First name and age' }
        ],
        items: [
          { name: { first: 'John', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Male', age: 42 },
          { name: { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe' }, sex: 'Female', age: 36 },
          { name: { first: 'Rubin', last: 'Kincade' }, sex: 'Male', age: 73 },
          { name: { first: 'Shirley', last: 'Partridge' }, sex: 'Female', age: 62 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image]